# dom css not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change the canvas left margin from javascript 'cause I want to use variables. But somehow, the code doesn't working. This is my code

```js
var upbicanvas = document.getElementById("upbi");
var upbictx = upbicanvas.getContext("2d");

var upbiimage = new Image();

upbiimage.onload = function () {
    console.log("Loading Top Image...");
    upbictx.drawImage(upbiimage, 1400, 0, 2500, 2600, 0, 0, upbicanvas.width, upbicanvas.height);
}

upbiimage.src = "images/BI.jpg";
var w = screen.width;
var h = screen.height / 15;
var uph = screen.height / 2;
var mleft = -1 * (w / 45);
var uppercanvas = document.getElementById("upperbi");

uppercanvas.height = h;
uppercanvas.width = w;
uppercanvas.style.marginLeft = mleft;
upbicanvas.width = w;
```

The uppercanvas.style.marginLeft part doesn't working. Anyone know what's wrong and how to solve it?

Sorry if my english bad..

Comment: CSS margin style values require units, eg `px`. Try `= \`${mleft}px\` `

Comment: FYI, you can calculate values in CSS without JavaScript using `calc()`, eg `#upperbi { margin-left: calc (100% / -45); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the **unit** that you want `mleft` to represent.

Instead of `uppercanvas.style.marginLeft = mleft` you're looking for:

```
uppercanvas.style.marginLeft = mleft + "px"
```

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var w = screen.width;
var h = screen.height / 15;
var uph = screen.height / 2;
var mleft = -1 * (w / 45);

var uppercanvas = document.getElementById("upperbi");
uppercanvas.style.marginLeft = mleft + "px";
```

```html
<div id="upperbi">Test</div>
```